# Javascript function not defined when published to Github

Tags: javascript, html, css

I create a function that should make my div visible on click. It works fine locally, but when I publish my project on Github pages I get an error "**Uncaught ReferenceError: btnClick is not defined
at HTMLElement.onclick ((index):51)**". Here's the script code:

```
document.getElementById('btn-share').onclick = function btnClick() {

  let comma = document.getElementById('comm-share');
  let tri = document.getElementById('trio');

  if (comma.style.visibility === "hidden") {

    comma.style.visibility = 'visible';
    tri.style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
  else {
    comma.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    tri.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
};
```

Image: [HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8iVf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is assigning the .onclick while making another function called `btnClick()`.
There are a few ways to fix your code:

```js
document.getElementById('btn-share').onclick = function () {
  let comma = document.getElementById('comm-share');
  let tri = document.getElementById('trio');

  if (comma.style.visibility === "hidden") {

    comma.style.visibility = 'visible';
    tri.style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
  else {
    comma.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    tri.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
};
```

This doesn't make any `btnClick()` but just assigns a function to `onclick`. This would be the best choice if you wanted to call `btnClick()` when you wanted to (well, you can do element.onclick).

```js
function btnClick() {
  let comma = document.getElementById('comm-share');
  let tri = document.getElementById('trio');

  if (comma.style.visibility === "hidden") {

    comma.style.visibility = 'visible';
    tri.style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
  else {
    comma.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    tri.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
};
document.getElementById('btn-share').onclick = btnClick;
```

The above assigns it to the function.

```js
document.getElementById('btn-share').addEventListener("click", function() {
  let comma = document.getElementById('comm-share');
  let tri = document.getElementById('trio');

  if (comma.style.visibility === "hidden") {

    comma.style.visibility = 'visible';
    tri.style.visibility = 'visible';
  } else {
    comma.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    tri.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
});
```

And the last one uses the `.addEventListener()` function to assign the function to the `onclick`.

It's your choice what you want to use.